# Executing linux command using python subprocess

Tags: python, linux, grep, subprocess

I have a requirement where I need to extract port number from a file `example.ini`, this file is in linux directory.

Now when I am executing below command from CLI its giving exact result which I want

```
$ cat path/example.ini | grep -i variable | cut -d '=' -f 2
```

however I want run this command using python script using `subprocess.run`

I am executing in script

```py
subprocess.run(['cat', 'path', '|', 'grep -i variable', '|', 'cut -d "=" -f2'])
```

I am getting error: `No such file or directory`

Comment: It seems like you wrote `path` instead of `path/example.ini`

Comment: that I have written here for example
in actual command it is
cat /var/tmp/backup/agent.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why use cat with grep ?
grep -i variable path/example.ini | cut -d '=' -f 2

```
import subprocess

ps = subprocess.Popen(('grep', '-i', 'variable', 'path/example.ini'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = subprocess.check_output(('cut', '-d', '=', '-f', '2'), stdin=ps.stdout)
ps.wait()
print(output.decode("utf-8")) # bytes object to UTF8
```

I simplified my solution

```
import subprocess

ps = subprocess.Popen(('grep', '-i', 'variable', 'path/example.ini'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = subprocess.run(('cut', '-d', '=', '-f', '2'), stdin=ps.stdout).stdout
```

Comment: Thank You. I am able to run now and we can also run this command with res = os.popen('linux command').read()